# How to pop up Enable Bluetooth prompt from Google Play Services?

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-play-services, android-settings

Application I'm working on uses both Locations and BLE and if location or bluetooth are disabled I have to ask user to enable them.

Latest Google Play Services provides a standard way to do that using `LocationSettingsRequest` which checks requirements and raises standard popup if changes to settings are required. It works like a charm for location alone but once I add `SetNeedBle (true)` to `LocationSettingsRequest` I get a status `SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE`.

The only my guess was I need to add `AddApi (FitnessClass.BLE_API)` call to a `GoogleApiClientBuilder` as it might be vital for BLE functionality, but then I got connection to Google Play Services failed with `SIGN_IN_REQUIRED` status which is confusing as I just need BLE part of Fitness service.

Does anyone know good example of `LocationSettingsRequest` usage to prompt user for both locations and bluetooth?

[image: Location popup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like it has been fixed in 8.1.0 so `SetNeedBle (true)` works as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. In the `LocationSettingsRequest.Builder` there is `setNeedBle(boolean needBle)` which will pop up a dialog box to ask for BLE.  Don't use the Fitness API for BLE location.

Also ensure that the phone is BLE enable by adding into the manifest:

```
<manifest>
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Then in you code :

```
if(context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
    //has BLE
}
```

And from Google Play Service you can use the [SettingApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi) which ask the system about available features. The guide contains a full example of how to use it.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationSettingsRequest.Builder.html#setNeedBle(boolean)

Comment: I have tried this before but what I get is `SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE` status. Do you have a working sample?

Comment: Which version of android are you targeting ? You can avoid phone without BLE on the manifest with `<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />`

Comment: Application already has mentioned lines in the manifest and I was trying `setNeedBle(boolean)` on Samsung Galaxy S3 (4.3) and LG G3 (5.0). Both times it gave me `SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE`.